# passing data in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, frontend

I developed a simple online shop. I want to pass/submit data from a js.file to another js. first js file contains display of item. then i want to pass data item to cart.js that contains a table.

```
<section className="products">

        <div className="product-card">
            <div className="product-image">
                <img src={ bagiak }/>
            </div>
            <div className="product-info">
                <h5>Bagiak Tidur</h5>
                <h6>Rp.12000</h6>
                <p>Masukkan Jumlah yang dibeli : </p><input type="number"/><br/><br/>
                <a href="/keranjang" className="button is-success btn-product"><i className="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Beli</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;

            </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

how i define data ("product" = "bagiak tidur", "Price" = "12000", "Quantity"="1") that i want to pass to table? and when i hit button data is entered to table.
Here's my table.

```
 <table id="cart" className="table table-hover table-condensed">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th styles="width:50%" className="text-center">Nama Produk</th>
                                <th styles="width:10%" className="text-center">Harga</th>
                                <th styles="width:8%" className="text-center">Jumlah</th>
                                <th styles="width:22%" className="text-center">Subtotal</th>
                                <th styles="width:10%" className="text-center">Action</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        {this.state.json.map((data, i) => {
                            var subtotal = data.harga*data.jumlah;
                            const id = data.id;

                        return (
                            <tr key={i}>
                                <td data-th="Product">
                                    <div className="row">

                                        <div className="col-sm-10">
                                            <h4 className="nomargin">{data.nama_barang}</h4>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td data-th="Price">Rp.{data.harga}</td>
                                <td data-th="Quantity">{data.jumlah} </td>
                                <td data-th="Subtotal" className="text-center">Rp.{subtotal}</td>
                                <td className="actions" data-th="">
                                    <button onClick={ () => this.handleDelete(id) } className="button is-danger"><i className="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>                             
                                </td>
                            </tr>);
                        })}  
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <td><Link to ="/" className="button is-warning"><i className="fa fa-angle-left"></i> Lanjut Berbelanja</Link></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>Total </td>
                                <td className="hidden-xs text-center"><strong>Rp. { total }</strong></td>
                                <td><Link to ="/transaksi" className="button is-success">Checkout <i className="fa fa-angle-right"></i></Link></td>
                            </tr>

                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
```

i developed UI website. so it doesnt connect with any database. All data is just on ui level. hope you know what i mean. sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 2):

In react, data can be passed from parent to child component via props. In your case, i am assuming, you are trying to pass data between same level components or sibling components. Either you can use callbacks which can be tricky or you might have to look into state management library like Redux which helps in data flow.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass data one component to another component. In this case these components are parent/child. You can pass the data with props.

In your parent component, you can pass your data with these three props.

```
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state = {
data = [{
  "id":1,
  "name":'sampleName'
},
{
  "id":2,
  "name":'sampleName2'
}]
};

}
render(){
  let myPropData="string";
   return(
      <ChildComponent passData={this.state.data} />
   );
}
```

In your child component's render method will be like this.

```
render(){
let propData = this.props.passData;
return(
//Do whatever you want. Display in table or grid etc...
);
}
```